# Animate button click during http call with angular

Tags: angular

I have a button to refresh data on a page, which is simply doing an http call to a backend.
It works fine but I'm trying to add a CSS3 animation to make it rotate while the http call is going on in the background, to make it obvious that something is happening.

```html
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right mr-1" (click)="refresh('all')">
            <i class="mdi mdi-refresh" [ngClass]="{'refresh-enabled': refreshAnimation}" type="button"></i>
          </button>
```

```css
@keyframes rotate360
{
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.refresh-enabled
{
  animation: 2s rotate360 infinite linear;
}
```

That animation works well if in the refresh function I set refreshAnimation to true and do nothing else.
But if I also do an http call, then it doesn't rotate. I'm guessing that's because the http call is blocking the function so that class doesn't get evaluated in the html until the call ends ?

```js
  refresh(region : string)
  {
      this.refreshAnimation = true;
      this.myservice.refreshAll().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(_ => this.loadMyData());
      this.refreshAnimation = false;
  }
```

What would be the correct way to achieve this, is there a way for me to return my call from this function and let angular finish it in the background, or am I doing it wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: you need the http request to be async so it doesn't immediately navigate away from your current page.

Comment: Any tip on how I'd do that ? I already thought using subscribe would do that, but clearly I was mistaken

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, I just need to return my subscription :

```js
  refresh(region : string)
  {
    this.refreshAnimation = true;
    return this.myservice.refreshAll().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(_ => this.loadMyData());
  }
```